# How can I tail an arbitrary file using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to tail an arbitrary file from a Kubernetes pod using `kubectl`? `kubectl cp` doesn't appear to support this.  And I don't want to tail all the logs, which I know I could do with `kubectl logs -f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps with kubectl exec.

Untested, and I haven't done a lot with k8s but:

```
kubectl exec -i podname -- tail -f filename
```

Might work.

Comment: Yes. It should work in my opinion too. Just tested with cat so tail should work too.. 
`kubectl exec -it mongo-0 -c mongo -- cat /js-yaml.js`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Turns out that the issue I have is how to "tail" a remote *binary* file.   New question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337901/how-can-i-tail-a-remote-binary-file